# Devise custom layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I need some help here.

I'm using the Devise gem for authentication and I've set up my routes as follow

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'join', password: 'forgot-password', edit: 'settings'}
  root to: 'pages#index'
end
```

I am then using a different layout file for all devise views

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :layout_by_resource

  private

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller? && resource_name == :user
      "devise_custom"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```

This works fine but I would like to make an exception for devise users/edit.  So that the registrations edit action uses the application layout instead.

Please anyone, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

/ Jacob

Comment: Hi, have you looked at this section? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Create-custom-layouts

Answer (score 0):

According with [this section](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Create-custom-layouts), you can do something like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Layout per resource_name
    def layout_by_resource
      if devise_controller? && resource_name == :admin
        "layout_name_for_devise_admin"
      else
        "application"
      end
    end

    # Layout per resource_name AND action
    def layout_by_resource
      if devise_controller? && resource_name == :user && action_name == "new"
        "layout_name_for_devise"
      else
        "application"
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for your answer. That is right but I would like to have all the devise actions/views except registrations edit (only) to use the custom layout.